# android device manager not recognized by android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

run button is disabled though i have istalled Android Virtual Device[**Run button not enabled**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udPVg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest few things to try to click the run on the menu and then **Edit Configurations**, then click on **Android Application** on the left and click the **+** button.

Choose **Android Application** from the *pop-up menu*. Then pick the module (its normally **app** or something).

Then click **apply** and **ok**.

or if you didn't had a module to select from, try invoking the `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files` that might add the app to the drop down menu.

you can also try to:

- re-import the project in the android studio.
- re-starting the android studio software.

I really hope this helped, if not, please tell me so I can try and help you more, best of luck **!**

Comment: Please let us know which solution worked for you my friend.